# How to implement AutoComplete TextField using ControlsFX

Tags: java, javafx, autocomplete, controlsfx

I'm using the latest version(8.0.5) of ControlsFX and I think I need a little help with the AutoComplete TextField because I'm very new at this.

I got this code from [here](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-request/196/auto-complete-support-see-127/diff)

```
AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding.createBinding(
MyTxtField,
SuggestionProvider.create("Hey", "Hello", "Hello World", "Apple", "Cool", "Costa", "Cola", "Coca Cola")
);
```

But it show a error: `method SuggestionProvider is not applicable.`

Any advice to implement this autocomplete in order to have an array like a dictionary with `ID` and `VALUE`?

Answer (score 7):

If you check the transcript to which you have quoted the code
https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-request/196/auto-complete-support-see-127/diff (early feb)
and the release date of controlsfx 8.05 dated 4 march http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/ , likely explanation is that the code is likely not working because what  you have quoted is just experimental API that yet to be finalized then. The final version is the one currently working in the final 8.05
as in

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(
            textField,
            "Hey", "Hello", "Hello World", "Apple", "Cool", "Costa", "Cola", "Coca Cola");
```

and other API you can check using autocomplete from your IDE

I recommend checking out controlfx 8.05 samples to look at the source code and that will help a lot :}

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can use the `AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding` as the following:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
new AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding(textField, new Callback<AutoCompletionBinding.ISuggestionRequest, Collection>() {
    @Override
    public Collection call(AutoCompletionBinding.ISuggestionRequest param) {
        return Arrays.asList("Option 1", "Option 2");
    }
});
```